# Versification of a drama

Tags: poetry, playwriting

I have originally written a drama in prose. However, now I am considering writing it in verse. Thus, I have the following questions:

1.) *Is this common practice (writing drama in verse)?*

2.) *Is there a specific versification that ought to be followed, or can I just distribute the text into sentences or parts of sentences (when they are longer) that carry a complete meaning?*

Comment: Please don't delete questions after they've been answered. Stack Exchange is a Q&A repository designed to help anyone who has the same problem as you, not just you, so deleting your questions serves to deny anyone else the same solution. Additionally, having too many deleted questions can trigger an automated question ban. I will be undeleting this and the other answered question you have deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't know what you are doing, in two ways.

First, it is common practise to be familiar with what you want to write. Writers of science fiction have been reading lots of science fiction and know the conventions of the genre. Writers of news reports have been reading (or watching) lots of news reports and know the conventions of the genre. And so on.

Second, poets – that is writers of verse – can only write good verse if they know what verse is. Does it have to rhyme? Does it have to have a certain metre? What makes some text verse while other texts aren't verse?

I don't understand why you would want to write something that apparently you are completely unfamiliar with, and that's none of my business. However, I am quite convinced that no amount of explanation that we could give you can compensate that lack of familiarity.

The first thing, in my opinion, that you need to do is read lots of verse drama (and poetry) so that your understanding of the form and its conventions becomes intuitive.

If I have drawn the wrong conclusions from your brief question and have misjudged your expertise, please forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it common to write drama in verse?

No, not for a long time. Think Marlow or Shakespeare when it was common.

More recently, around 1907, [Robert W Service](https://allpoetry.com/The-Shooting-of-Dan-McGrew) did short stories in verse, but they were not strictly drama.  There was usually something comedic or wry about the characters or setting. They’re considered poems, because of the style. But they told full stories.

How you versify it?

I have no idea, but imagine that you’d need to be consistent through an entire piece.  Like maybe one piece is in quatrains — whatever they are — and another is rhyming couplets.  But don’t mix different poetic structures in the same piece. That is just a guess, honestly.

I wish you good luck on what sounds like an ambitious project

Answer (score 0):

Plays in verse (and rhyming verse at that) were relatively popular until the 19th century or so, but nowadays such stylisation would be rare. The newest I can think of is Cyrano de Bergerac, 1897. (I mean, there's Manon Lescaut by Nezval, 1940, but I doubt its fame is international.)

If you write a play in verse, count on it to be a fairly niche thing.

If you decide to go this way, there's no strict rule about the form of the verse - rhyming, metric, or even free. Consider how the form fits the content - if the setting is medieval Tokyo then maybe classical hexameter won't be your first choice, or perhaps you don't think blankverse is a good match for a farce. You can, of course, deliberately work with a contrast; you just need to know if the effect is what you're going for.

Mixing more than one form isn't strictly forbidden either, but with most plots it would probably be a distracting element and unadvisable. (On the other hand, I think I would enjoy something like a time-traveling story where each scene would be rendered in a form popular in the given era.)

That a line should be a unit of meaning is a good observation and one that many people attempting to write epic poetry ignore way too often. (Drama in verse and epic poetry have a lot in common.) But unless you're working with free verse, it's far from all. Depending on the form you choose, there may be much more - rhythm, rhymes, alliterations.

It's a risky terrain. Verse in which there's anything off (for instance, syllable stresses in the wrong places) is very unpleasant to follow. And a whole play is a lot of work to commit to. If you choose to dedicate so much effort, you should be confident about your skill to make it work. If you aren't sure at writing poetry in general, you might end up investing a lot of sweat - to the detriment of the quality of your piece.